# Twitter rate limits, authentication and how to get followers with oauth

Tags: twitter

My understanding about the twitter api is that the get request limit raises from 150 per hour to 450 per hour if authentication has been granted from the user.

My company web app will have ~50 simultaneous users and since the requests are going through our server they will be sent to twitter from the same ip address and so the get requests will quickly reach the limits. However, if I had oauth in place (which I do for sending tweets) rather than all the users requests be taken from the collective pool of 150 limited requests, **EACH** user would have 450 requests per hour.

Is this correct?

A big part of my web application is using /followers/ids from the twitter api to get the followers of various different people on twitter. So if a user logs in, they will be able to get the followers of 5 different people they have specified. I want to do this using their quota of 450 requests per hour, not the ip restricted quota of 150 per hour across all users of the web application.

Is this possible and if so, how - roughly? It's easy to get the current logged in users followers but I don't know how to get other followers using oauth and using the 450 individual quota.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are right, but the number is not 450 it is 350.  https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting

When user logs in with twitter you get his oAuth credentials, you should save them in database, they are valid until user revokes them in twitter.com (very rarely). Now every time you need something from twitter API, get random user form database and use his oauth info to sign the request. *unless you need something user specific - then you should use the right user*